# HTML Select only drops down in IE on the primary monitor

Tags: html, asp.net, internet-explorer, select, selectlist

The following `select` list only drops down on the primary monitor in IE 8

I can click on the control and use arrow to scroll down but it will not display by clicking to display the list.

**Is there a fix for this?**

```
<td>
    <select name="dpApprovers" id="dpApprovers">
        <option value="none">---SELECT---</option>
        <option value="a">A</option>
        <option value="b">B</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

**Edit - Explanation:** I have 3 monitors. If the browser is in the primary monitor you are able to click on the drop down list and it will display the options. If the browser is on the 2nd monitor (directly above the primary monitor), the drop down will display at the top of the primary monitor (below). If the browser is on the 3rd monitor (right of the primary), clicking on the drop down list will do nothing (not display the options).

Comment: You question to me is unclear. Now general speaking the drop down list is part of the system controls and you can not change the behavior of it, what you can is to make a custom dropdownlist using javascript and make the behavior you like. The custom drop down list will be made using divs.

Comment: I have added a clearer explaination @Aristos